# Make ul align on the right verticle

Tags: html, css

Thanks for viewing my issue.

I was wondering how do I make the ul align on the right of the div vertically. I just don't really know that much of CSS and HTML. Can anyone help me out?? The ul is horizontal and want it to be vertical as shown in the attached picture.

[image: example]

**CSS**

```
#userStats { display: block; width: auto; background-color: #f9f9f9; border: 1px solid #ccc; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; padding: 12px; }

#userStats .pic { float: left; display: block; margin-right: 10px; }
#userStats .pic a img { padding: 7px; background: #fff; border: 1px solid #ccc; }

#userStats .data {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 515px;
    height: 166px;
    padding: 4px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    background: #e6e6e6;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
#userStats .data h1 { color: #474747; line-height: 1.6em; text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #fff; }
#userStats .data h3 { color: #666; line-height: 0.9em; margin-bottom: 5px; }
#userStats .data h4 { font-size: 1.2em; line-height: 1.3em; }

#userStats .data .socialMediaLinks { position: absolute; right: 6px; top: 8px; }
#userStats .data .socialMediaLinks a img { margin-right: 5px; }

#userStats .data .sep { clear: both; margin-top: 20px; width: 485px; height: 1px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; margin-bottom: 0; }
#userStats .data ul.numbers { list-style: none; width: 320px; padding-top: 7px; margin-top: 0; border-top: 1px solid #fff; color: #676767; }
#userStats .data ul.numbers li { width: 95px; float: left; display: block; padding-left: 8px; height: 50px; border-right: 1px dotted #bbb; text-transform: uppercase; }
#userStats .data ul.numbers li strong { color: #434343; display: block; font-size: 3.4em; line-height: 1.1em; font-weight: bold; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="data">
 <h1>Bill Gates</h1>
 <h3>CEO of Microsoft Corporation</h3>
 <h3>San Francisco, CA</h3>
 <h4><a href="http://spyrestudios.com/">http://spyrestudios.com/</a></h4>
 <div class="socialMediaLinks">
    <a href="http://twitter.com/jakerocheleau" rel="me" target="_blank">
      <img src="img/twitter.png" alt="@jakerocheleau" />
    </a>
    <a href="http://gowalla.com/users/JakeRocheleau" rel="me" target="_blank">
       <img src="img/gowalla.png" />
    </a>
  </div>
<div class="sep"></div>
  <ul class="numbers clearfix">
    <li>Reputation<strong>185</strong></li>
    <li>Checkins<strong>344</strong></li>
    <li class="nobrdr">Days Out<strong>127</strong></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: give `float:right;` for your class .numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just float the list to the right

```
.numbers {
    float:right;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/A6tZP/2/)**

Comment: Thanks. But that just aligned the text to the right. How can I align it so that its verticle?

Comment: Thanks for replying Daniel:). I have updated and uploaded an image of the thing I'm looking for.

Comment: @user3284463 - It's already vertical - but in any case I updated the fiddle to look a little more like your image

Comment: and don´t forget to use a `float:clear;` after the floated element :)

Answer (score 0):

Give float your `UL`

```
.numbers { float:right }
```